# Fast Fourier transfrom

Tags: fourier-analysis

What are the prerequisites for understanding the fast fourier transform for fast multiplication? What topics should I be familiar with first?

Comment: Knowing the discrete Fourier transform helps :).

Comment: There is actually a beautiful explanation of Gilbert Strang of the FFT.

Comment: @Surb And to learn discrete FT? I mean, what topics I need to understand. From calculus maybe linear algebra etc. Hope I am clear.

Comment: I suggest you the book *Discrete Time Signal Processing (Alan Oppenheim)*. Read some sections of chapters 2,8 and 9.

Comment: @notorious The way I got introduced to it, we needed to know about Lebesgues spaces (also dominated convergence theorem) and Kernels (Fejér kernel, Dirichlet kernel, Poisson kernel and then Cesaro average). Knowing about complex (and vectorial) analysis helps also a lot.